# how is tensorflow reduce_sum finding the intersection in the below code for dice coefficient?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow

In the below code I am not able to grasp how multiplying y_true and y_pred and putting reduce_sum on it gives the intersection between the two

```
def dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred):
    numerator = 2 * tensorflow.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred)
    denominator = tensorflow.reduce_sum(y_true + y_pred)
```

In numerator, why are we multiplying the predicted and true labels? and how is reduce sum finding the intersection?

**If we take an example:**
lets say our true pixels were [5,2,3,7,7] and predicted pixels were [4,2,3,9,7].
So we have 3 intersecting pixels hence numerator must be 2*3=6
denominator=5+5=10, hence dice coeff  = 6/10=0.6

**However, the way reduce sum is working is this:**

[5,2,3,7,7] * [4,2,3,9,7] = [20, 4, 9, 63, 49]
reduce_sum( [20, 4, 9, 63, 49] ) i.e 20+4+9+63+49 = 145
hence, numerator = 2*145 = 290

[5,2,3,7,7] + [4,2,3,9,7] = [9,4,6,16,14]
Denominator = reduce_sum( [9,4,6,16,14] ) i.e 9+4+6+16+14 = 49
hence, dice coeff  = 290/49 = 5.91

**How is reduce_sum() finding the intersection of pixels?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dice coefficient is used to measure the overlap of two sets. It is defined as $$D(X,Y)=2\frac{|X \cap Y|}{|X|+|Y|}$$.

The only way this expression is a valid implementation of the Dice coefficient is if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, where $|X| + |Y| > 0$.

In terms of tensors, one way to denote set membership is to use binary encoding, so the tensors take on the value of 1 whenever an element is a member of some set, and 0 otherwise. Since you mention pixels, I surmise that you're working on a problem that involves boolean masks for your images. These can be represented as binary tensors, taking the value of 1 when the object of interest is present, and 0 otherwise. If you're working with photos of dogs, you would use 1 to denote all of the pixels where dogs are present, 0 otherwise.

Thus the multiplication of two tensors of binary encodings gives you the *intersection*, because the only time that you get the value of `1` is `1 * 1`; all other products yield zero. Summing all of these `1`s tells you the cardinality of the intersection. This is what the `numerator` expresses in your code.

Taking the sum of the binary tensors gives you the cardinality of the two tensors, hence the `denominator`.

I think the gap in your understanding is the assumption that the outputs are non-binary; if you supply these types of inputs, then there is not a correspondence to the definition of the Dice coefficient.

Comment: okay.. i get it now! You were right. I assumed the predicted pixels to be non-binary. Thanks for the clarification